# lenovo s1 yoga laptop freezes when connected to external monitor

Tags: drivers, display, external-monitor

I am an Ubuntu newbie here so please pardon me in advance. I just got an external monitor today and my laptop completely freezes when I connect the monitor to the laptop via HDMI and I have to reboot.

This issue only occurs when the screen is connected after the laptop is put on but if I connect the monitor before putting on the laptop, all is well.

I have tried searching but can't find anything related to my laptop but the laptop kernel and display graphics information has been requested from people trying to help out so I thought I paste these below:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

> *-display
>          description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 2
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>          version: 0b
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>          resources: irq:46 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

```
uname -r
```

> 5.0.0-32-generic

Laptop information:

> Model No: 20C0S0HR00 (LENOVO_MT_20C0_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad S1 Yoga)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The i915 driver for yr Intel APU is included already in the Linux kernel. As to yr screen, well, https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-YOGA-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-YOGA/20CD and https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/s1_yoga_hmm_en_sp40a26742_01.pdf don't show the screen resolution. It _may_ be 1920x1280, but would you please flip it over, and find the model # that's on the same sticker as the serial # then click [edit] here & paste the model # in yr question?  Thay way, we can know for sure, as there are multiple Yoga S1 PCs

Comment: Thank you @K7AAY. I have updated the question with the model no.